# Is SVG ellipse with "reverse fill" possible?

Tags: html, image, svg

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 1200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <image x="0" y="0" height="200" width ="100" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bc/IKB_191.jpg/1200px-IKB_191.jpg" />
  <ellipse cx="50" cy="100" rx="50" ry="62" fill="grey" />
</svg>
```

In the example above, we want to be able to see the image (the blue box) inside of the ellipse, and have the grey of the ellipse only show in the corners / on the outside. You could think of this like a portrait of a person (the image) with a border (the inverse-of-ellipse).

We have an SVG with an image and an ellipse. The SVG image doesn't have many attributes (no border radius), and so we thought to use an "inverse-filled" ellipse, where the fill color is on the **outside** of the ellipse rather than inside. Unfortunately this is not happening in our example. Is this possible with svg:ellipse? Or is there some other approach? We need the image in the SVG, and our goal is to create a curved "border" (think border-radius 50%) of a certain fill color placed in front of the image.

**Edit:** I could create an svg:path, or maybe there is some sort of clipping that can be placed over the image?

**Edit2:** this path is close but not quite there because there shouldn't be any blue inside of the ellipse created by the path...

```html
<svg height="200">
  <path 
    stroke="black" fill="blue" stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="0.5"
    d="
       M0 80
       a40 80 0 0 0 80 0 
       a40 80 1 0 0 -80 0
       l0 80 
       l80 0 
       l0 -160
       l-80 0
     " 
  />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve the deired result.  Here are a couple

**With a mask**

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 1200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <mask id="ellipse-mask">
      <ellipse cx="50" cy="100" rx="50" ry="62" fill="white" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="38" width="100" height="124" fill="gray"/>
  <image x="0" y="0" height="200" width ="100"
         xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bc/IKB_191.jpg/1200px-IKB_191.jpg"
         mask="url(#ellipse-mask)"/>
</svg>
```

**With a path or clipping path**

Your path was close. But you needed to close each subpath with a Z or z) so that they are individually filled.

```html
<svg height="200">
  <path 
    stroke="black" fill="blue" stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="0.5"
    d="
       M0 80
       a40 80 0 0 0 80 0 
       a40 80 1 0 0 -80 0
       Z
       M0 0 
       l80 0 
       l0 160
       l-80 0
       Z
     " 
  />
</svg>
```